# Giving hope to somebody

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

I wonder what phrasal verb/expression/idiom do you normally use in English for **giving someone hope**?

Please have a consideration in my examples:

> **A)** He is a very energetic and positive individual. He always helps his surrounding people. When I divorced I was very discouraged. **He gave me a lot of hope.** I'll never forget that.
>
> **B)** Yeah, I know him well. **He always gives hope to people.**

Are the defined sentences above natural?

Also, how can I thank someone who has been very hope-giving towards me? Can I say:

> - **Thank you for giving me hope.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is a pretty normal phrase in English (certainly in the UK).

**To give** - to offer something to someone, or to provide someone with something) [def.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/give)

**Hope** - the feeling that something desired can be had or will happen [def.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hope)

**To give [someone] hope** - to offer the feeling that something will happen

All your phrases make sense, I would just consider changing your word order for the following:

> He always gives people hope

Comment: Superb; just please tell me why did you rephrased "He always gives people hope"? Is it weong to use the structure: **"give hope to someone"** and I must always use **"give someone hope"** @Bee?

Comment: I don't believe the way you have written it is wrong. It just sounds more natural the way I have phrased it, I can't exactly put my finger on why.